# Changing a NSWindow view in code

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I would like to have a detail view come in to focus when the user double clicks on a table view row. How would I change a window's view in code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea would be as follows:

```
- (IBAction)tableViewDoubleClicked
{
    ...

    [window setContentView:myDetailView];
}
```

Note that this may release the view that was previously used as the `contentView` for the window, so if you are planning to swap around a couple of different content views, you will need to properly retain them elsewhere.

See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.